# What makes possible assignation to a String without initialization?

Tags: java

This is a bit of a weird question that came today on our java course and the teacher didn't really know how to answer.

In java you can create a `String` (or any kind of class variable; `Integer`, `Boolean`, ...) by doing `String x = "some text";`.

However, if you specify a specific class `CustomString` and you try to initialize it with `CustomString x = "some text";` it will give an error.

Thing is after diving a bit in the String class I can't really find what makes it different and why does it allow this behavior, could someone explain how it does it?

Furthermore, can we make a class with this behavior? Or is it specific for Java types?

Comment: String is the way it is because that is how it was defined per the [JLS, the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)

Comment: "Furthermore, can we make a class with this behavior?" -- No, String is the exception

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels for linking a related question, I couldn't find it at all, and for the aclaration. What about Integer, Boolean and so on? They are also exceptions?

Comment: They are classes that wrap primitives and so yes, are exceptions. The JLS will tell you the specifics on them.